# Wiki Links in a Sharepoint List?

Tags: list, wiki

Is there a way to use wiki links inside a SharePoint list? I've used a calculated column in number format to create an HTML link, and I tried that with a wiki title, but it doesn't work. Are there any precedents/methods to achieve a wiki link in a SharePoint list?